# Number of products are not matching on category page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.5

I have **20 products in a category**. But when I open the same category on **frontend it shows 11 products.** I logged the query and directly fired on the database, it correctly shows 20 records. But for the same query result is 11 on category page. What could be the reason.

Comment: Checked Quantity of product !!! they all  20 products have quantity and status in stock ?

Comment: yes I did checked.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons for it. Few which I can list

1. Product is **out of stock**
2. Product **status** is **Disabled**
3. Product **visibility** does not include **Catalog**
4. Product is **not assigned** to that particular **website**

Comment: we have already looked into these possibilities. But they are set correctly. Still the products are not getting displayed properly. And moreover, why the same query gives proper result when fired on database?.